# Sum a row until a certain value is reached

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I need to sum values in row 2 until it reaches the specified number in A1 then stop and show 0s after. For example, in A1 you have the value you want to reach, for instance, 5. In cell c1 you have 1, d1 you have 2, e1 you have 3, f1 you have 4, and g1 you have 5. In cell c2 it should show a 1, in d2 a 3, in e2 a 5, then a zero in f2 and g2.

=MIN(SUM($C$1:C1),$A$1)

This is what I tried..... It works but does show the max number after the desired number is shown rather than a zero.

Comment: `=IF(SUM($C$1:C1)>=$A$1,0,SUM($C$1:C1))`

Comment: The cell e2 should show a 5. With this formula, it shows a 3.

Comment: @George did you drag this down? it is designed to do a cumulative sum, which you asked for, using relative addressing.

Answer (score 3):

### Sum Up Until 'Breach'

```
=LET(br,C1:G1,bp,A1,bv,0,
    sc,SCAN(0,br,LAMBDA(rr,r,MIN(rr+r,bp))),
    m,XMATCH(bp,sc),
    s,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(br)),
IF(ISNA(m),sc,IF(s>m,bv,sc)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say "If the sum is smaller than a value, show that sum, else show 0".
In a formula:

```
=IF(SUM($B1:B1)<=20;SUM($B1:B1);0)
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

The dollar-sign in front of the `B` in `$B1` makes sure that this value does not change, if you drag your formula to the right.

Instead of `0`, another value can be used too:

```
=IF(SUM($B1:B1)<=20;SUM($B1:B1);20)
```

[image]

... and if you want the whole thing to be finished with zeroes:

```
=IF(OR(F2=20;F2=0);0;IF(SUM($B1:G1)<=20;SUM($B1:G1);20))
```

[image]

Comment: OP wants a `20` in `G2`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: sorry, I didn't get your remark at first.

Comment: ... but zeros after (to the right of) it.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Now we should be there :-)

Comment: Almost! It doesn't work with sum value<=0, it doesn't work if first row starts with 0 (B1). While these two might not be the case here, it doesn't work if A2 cell is empty. I think that should be stated as it might be confusing to adapt :)

Comment: @user11222393: let's await a reaction from the question author.

Comment: Until then it is solved. +1

Comment: This is great. However, the first numbers will most likely be zeros resulting in all zeros using this formula. I changed the formula to this =IF(F2=20,0,IF(SUM($B1:G1)<=20,SUM($B1:G1),20)), but now it sums after hitting the max number. Anyway to do this with the first number or numbers being a zero?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using Reduce:

```
=LET(range,C1:G1,
limit,A1,
DROP(REDUCE(0,range,LAMBDA(a,c,HSTACK(a,IF(MAX(a)>=limit,0,MIN(TAKE(a,,-1)+c,limit))))),,1))
```

provided the limit is positive.

[image]

This should work for a negative limit:

```
=LET(range,C1:G1,
limit,A1,
DROP(REDUCE(limit-1,range,LAMBDA(a,c,HSTACK(a,IF(MAX(a)>=limit,0,MIN(IF(COLUMNS(a)=1,c,TAKE(a,,-1)+c),limit))))),,1))
```

[image]